# how to send text message from android application using 4 digit numbers

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Is it possible to send the message to recipient through my android application with the 4 number, means the recipient will receive the message from 4 digit number.

Comment: Are you asking about an application you wrote or the default text message app in Android?

Comment: yes my application that is develop ,sends sms to the recipients. I have an activity that has feedback string and number input.

Comment: smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, "Thank you for your valuable feedback.", null, null)

Comment: You can't do it with the [`sendTextMessage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) procedure. Unfortunately I'm not experienced in Android enough to be able to give a solution.